# cakephp is not able to connect to database

Tags: php, database, cakephp

I am a cakephp newbie and I tried to setup my connection to mysql. I had it worked before but after I changed my mysql database name, it won't connect anymore even thought I changed the database name in database.php inside the config folder. Do I have to run the cakephp console again??

```
Your tmp directory is writable.

The FileEngine is being used for caching. To change the config edit APP/config/core.php

Your database configuration file is present.

Cake is NOT able to connect to the databa
```

Above is the message shown. 
Any ideas what I have to do? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that the new database allows the user in the database.php file to have access to the new database. Look at the [MySQL GRANT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/grant.html) syntax.

Comment: Well I would then setup a simple test script that uses mysql_connect and see what error it is throwing and try running some simple queries on the database you are trying to use / access.